# Increase the value of a field of a resource in a RESTful API by a fixed amount without knowing it's value

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm working on an API that is responsible for managing long running jobs.
You create jobs by posting to

```
/jobs/
```

which gives you an object with a progress field like so

```
{"progress_percentage": 0.0, "id": 1}
```

You can then make changes to the instance of this job by patching to

```
/jobs/<job-id>/
```

While the jobs are running I want to hit the api to increase the progress as the job is running, starting at 0.0, ending at 100.0.
Any given job can be split into smaller tasks, these tasks can run concurrently, and can be assigned progress 'chunks'.
I want each chunk to increase the progress relative to it's assigned progress.
For example if task 1 is running and is assigned a progress chunk of 30% and there is a for loop in this task of size 5, I would want to increase the progress percentage by 6% for each iteration of that for loop, regardless of what the current progress percentage is.

Other jobs may just simply want to set the percentage (not increase it)

My question then is, what would be the most desirable way to do this from an API design point of view.

I see a few options

1.

```
PATCH /jobs/<job-id>/
```

with a payload of

```
{"progress_percentage": {"increase": 6.0}}
```

to increase

or

```
{"progress_percentage": {"set": 35.0}}
```

to set.

2.

```
POST /jobs/<job-id>/progress_percentage/
```

with a payload of

```
{"amount" 6.0} or [6.0]
```

to increase or

```
PATCH /jobs/<job-id>/
```

with a payload of

```
{"progress_percentage" 30.0}
```

to set.

Comment: Is your API managing some worker-shards and assigning them some jobs to do and now you want the shards informing the server/API about the progress on the assigned job? In such a case I would refrain from providing a HTTP interface to alter the state in general as you probably don't want to give arbitrary clients the possibility to perform some updates on your jobs. Usually such things shoud be done in the back, transparent for the clients i.e. by utilizing messaging queueing in order to trigger work on the worker nodes and respond back results.

Comment: @RomanVottner yes, when a job is created we start a job by pushing the job object onto a queue which will then be picked up by a job scheduler/executer. We want these job schedulers/executers to report back to the API the current status of the running job (progress, has it finished yet etc). Are you suggesting to do this by having the job runners/executers pushing messages to a queue? If so, I don't see the advantage of this over just hitting the API, as well, this would mean having to implement another service which consumes this queue.

Comment: The advantage here is simply separation of concerns. If you expose such a thing in your API, it becomes part of your API for eternity, giving clients the option to alter the progress state of jobs if it feels like so, which should clearly be only done from within your backend nodes. Introducing an extra channel here avoids such a clunkiness. If you convert your design to regular Web pages, which is a good design approach if you are aiming for a REST architecture, would it feel natural to you if backend nodes call endpoints on your public API?

Comment: In addition to that, the spelling of URIs or what methods you invoke on such URIs is not of relevance in a REST architecture as long as you don't violate constraints outlined by REST itself or by its transport protocol, HTTP. There are even proposals to avoid giving resources names that are meaningful to humans as this, with high certainty, leads to [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). If you still insist on exposing it via your API I at least recommend to [read this](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/)

Comment: "would it feel natural to you if backend nodes call endpoints on your public API" I guess not :) 
I see what you're getting at now. Awesome, thanks @RomanVottner, will look into using message queues for this and will read both this articles. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your REST API is not publicly exposed,I believe option 1 to be more favourable.

As 'progress_percentage' is a property of the 'job' object, I don't see the need to introduce a sub-resource (i.e. **/progress_percentage**).

Also, if you'd want to execute a PATCH for multiple 'job' attributes, you'd want to be able to do it as part of a single request and payload, rather than triggering multiple PATCH requests. For that, usage of '**PATCH /jobs/{job-id}/**' makes sense.